# NSLocalizedStringFromTable not falling back to English?

Tags: ios, localization

If you have an iOS App that is localized in, say, English and French, and you set your device to German, NSLocalizedString() will fall back to the English version of Localizable.strings, which is fine.

If you add a new strings file, X.strings, localized in English and French, and you use NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"somekey", @"X", @""), that will only work for devices switched to English or French. If you switch your device to e.g. German, NSLocalizedStringFromTable() does not fall back to English, and simply returns the key, capitalized. I had expected it to fallback to English, but it does not.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Hm. NSLocalizedStringFromTable() *does* fall back to English. I was testing in the simulator, only after deleting my App there, a clean and rebuilding it, it worked, suddenly.

Comment: I don't think it falls back to EN. It still returns the key as is if that localized strings file isn't present.

Comment: Having the same issue. It doesn't fall back to english. I tried cleaning project, delete derived files, deleting app, reset iOS simulator, no good.